# How to make curve top for UIVIew in swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

[image]

I want to give `curve` top to the view. I have used following code but it is not working properly.  I am using following code but it is not giving desirable output. Please help me.

Thanks.

```
func roundedTop(targetView:UIView?, desiredCurve:CGFloat?){

    let offset:CGFloat =  targetView!.frame.width/desiredCurve!
    let bounds: CGRect = targetView!.bounds        
    let rectBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y+bounds.size.height / 2, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height / 2)
    let rectPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
    let ovalBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x:bounds.origin.x - offset / 2,y: bounds.origin.y, width : bounds.size.width + offset, height :bounds.size.height)

    let ovalPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
    rectPath.append(ovalPath)

    // Create the shape layer and set its path
    let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = bounds
    maskLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath

    [![// Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the view's layer][1]][1]
    targetView!.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Top curve result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhXzE.png)
[Bottom curve result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWX8I.png)

Code in swift5

```
//TopRoundedCornerToView and BottomRoundedCornerToView

extension UIView {

func addTopRoundedCornerToView(targetView:UIView?, desiredCurve:CGFloat?)
{
    let offset:CGFloat =  targetView!.frame.width/desiredCurve!
    let bounds: CGRect = targetView!.bounds

    //Top side curve
    let rectBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y+bounds.size.height / 2, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height / 2)
    
    let rectPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
    
    //Top side curve
    let ovalBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - offset / 2, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + offset, height: bounds.size.height)
    
    let ovalPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
    rectPath.append(ovalPath)

    // Create the shape layer and set its path
    let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = bounds
    maskLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath

    // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the view's layer
    targetView!.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
    
    func setTopCurve(){
           let offset = CGFloat(self.frame.size.height/4)
           let bounds = self.bounds
           let rectBounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height/2  , width:  bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height / 2)
        
           let rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
           
         let ovalBounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x , y: bounds.origin.y - offset / 2, width: bounds.size.width + offset, height: bounds.size.height)
           let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
       rectPath.append(ovalPath)

           let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
           maskLayer.frame = bounds
           maskLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath
           self.layer.mask = maskLayer
       }
    
    func addBottomRoundedCornerToView(targetView:UIView?, desiredCurve:CGFloat?)
    {
        let offset:CGFloat =  targetView!.frame.width/desiredCurve!
        let bounds: CGRect = targetView!.bounds

        //Bottom side curve
        let rectBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height / 2)

        let rectPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
        
        //Bottom side curve
        let ovalBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - offset / 2, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + offset, height: bounds.size.height)
        
        let ovalPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
        rectPath.append(ovalPath)

        // Create the shape layer and set its path
        let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath

        // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the view's layer
        targetView!.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
        
        func setBottomCurve(){
               let offset = CGFloat(self.frame.size.height/4)
               let bounds = self.bounds
               
            let rectBounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y  , width:  bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height / 2)
               let rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)
               let ovalBounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - offset / 2, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width + offset, height: bounds.size.height)
            
               let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
           rectPath.append(ovalPath)

               let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
               maskLayer.frame = bounds
               maskLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath
               self.layer.mask = maskLayer
           }
}
```

**use it as**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.myTargateView.setTopCurve()
}
```

and

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.myTargateView.addTopRoundedCornerToView(targetView: bottomView, desiredCurve: 10.0)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling your `roundedTop` method *too soon* (probably in `viewDidLoad`). Wait until after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has been called for the first time. Otherwise, your `targetView.frame` and all the calculations that stem from it are incorrect.